# Public function in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, function

I want to write a global function for my whole project to use in every form. I tried creating a public module and create a public function, but when I call it to my form, it generates error.

let say my global function is about connection to the database. Then when I call it, it says that the connection property is not initialized.

In my function file, I used:

```
 Imports System.Data.SqlClient
 Public Module Connection
    Dim myConnection As SqlConnection
    Public Sub ConnectToDatabase()
       myConnection = New SqlConnection(".............")
       myConnection.Open()
    End Sub
 End Module
```

And in my form, I used:

```
 Private Sub Form_Load(...........) Handles MyBase.Load
    ConnectToDatabase()   'I call the function here
    ...............................................
 End Sub
```

And this does not work.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some code to show what is not working?

Comment: When you say "this does not work", how does it not work? I'm guessing "ConnectToDatabase()" is not recognised?  There may also be a design concern here - SqlConnections implement IDisposable; it is often best to surround them with "Using Statements".  In addition, it is usually not good to hold the connection open longer than is necessary.  Just minor observations to consider - let us know what the Exception/Compiler warning is

Comment: its error was `the connection property has not been initialized`.

Comment: On what line?  None of the lines you've provided consume the connection so I'm guessing in some different code?

Comment: the line below `ConnectToDatabase()`. They are such as `myCommand = New SqlCommand(".....",myConnection) myCommand.ExecuteScalar`. Thus it refuses the last statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this has nothing to do with the fact that this is a public module or public function and everything to do with the fact that you aren't initialising your connection correctly.

Try the following code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data

Public Sub ConnectToSQL()
    Dim con As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Try
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=atisource;Initial Catalog=BillingSys;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=12345678"
        con.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error while connecting to SQL Server." & ex.Message) Finally
        con.Close() 'Whether there is error or not. Close the connection.
    End Try
End Sub
```